# Android Google Places locate searched location on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Is it possible to locate the pin on the map when searching for a place in the google places Activity? Now, when I am searching a place in my app, I start the places Activity, there is a map and I am searching for a place. The place is found and a marker is added to the place, but the camera stays at my location...

Here's the code where I am starting the google places activity:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here's my OnActivityResult code:

```
public void action(Context context, Intent data, final TextView addressText, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient){
    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(context, data);
    if(addressText!=null) {
        Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, place.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                //Work with the data
                places.release();
            }
        });
            /*Show the address in to the text view with animation*/
        addressText.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.address_text_anim));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Use animate camera method.

 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(22.3075, 72.12345);
 CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
 map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: The thing is that I am only using Google Places API.. The activity that opens is not my activity, it's a google picl place activity... It's exactly like this: https://developers.google.com/places/images/placepicker.png

Comment: I've added my code in the question above.. There is nothing to see really, I've just implemented the google places API into my app. Than I am creating an Intent that starts the google places Activity.. And finally, in my OnActivityResult method, I am catching the data from the Places Activity...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng , yourdesiredvalue);
map.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: The thing is that I am only using Google Places API.. The activity that opens is not my activity, it's a google pick place activity... I don't have a map fragment. It's exactly like this: https://developers.google.com/places/images/placepicker.png